# Kaleidoscope of colors

Tags: riddle

I'm a kaleidoscope of colors,
Red, blue, green of sorts
You use me everyday,
Even now you're using me,
Or maybe my arch-rival...

Cool as he is, he's -
Mostly used offline!
Yet, he's vital to many prints,
Kaleidoscope, kaleidoscope...

My rival's smug, very, very smug,
He's comprised of more than me...
But he only subtracts, I add,
We're very under-hyped!

Kaleidoscope, kaleidoscope,
Part of a broader view!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a kaleidoscope of colors,
Red, blue, green of sorts
You use me everyday,
Even now you're using me,
Or maybe my arch-rival...

> My guess would be that kaleidoscope is [*RGB color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and arch-rival is [*CMYK color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)

Cool as he is, he's -
Mostly used offline!
Yet, he's vital to many prints,
Kaleidoscope, kaleidoscope...

> [*CMYK color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) is normally used in printers, so he's used offline and he's vital to many prints
>  And as [*rand al'thor*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) mentioned in his comment, the initial letters of the lines also form *CMYK*

My rival's smug, very, very smug,
He's comprised of more than me...
But he only subtracts, I add,
We're very under-hyped!

> [*CMYK color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) is comprised of 4 colors: *C*yan, *M*agenta, *Y*ellow and *K*ey(black), [*RGB color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) only consists of 3 colors: *R*ed, *G*reen and *B*lue.
>  From [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page):
>  The [*CMYK color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) (process color, four color) is a **subtractive** color model
>  The [*RGB color model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) is an additive color model

Kaleidoscope, kaleidoscope,
Part of a broader view!

**So my final answer is:**

> [**RGB color model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)

---

And a bit of how-I-got-there:

> RGB was really easy to figure out. Actually, it is in the question.
>  Then I thought that kaleidoscope could be the CRT(cathode ray tube), then the rival would be LCD/TFT
>  But I didn't find anything about adding/subtracting about CRT/LCD, so I started reading about RGB color model
>  In there I saw that this color model is additive, so I immediately went to other color models hoping to find a subtractive one
>  After I read the riddle again with those color models in my mind, everything made sense :)

Comment: You should mention the initial letters of the lines in the 2nd verse! :-)

Comment: Good, just figure out the last line and I'll accept. Not the kaleidoscope part, the part of a broader view part. Something to do with light :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you be:

> A computer screen

I'm a kaleidoscope of colors,
Red, blue, green of sorts
You use me everyday,
Even now you're using me,
Or maybe my arch-rival...

> Computer screens are made up of RGB components. The arch rival could refer to a TV instead of a monitor which some people use instead.

Cool as he is, he's -
Mostly used offline!
Yet, he's vital to many prints,
Kaleidoscope, kaleidoscope...

> TVs are normally used offline but are used for stories (related to prints/books?)

My rival's smug, very, very smug,
He's comprised of more than me...
But he only subtracts, I add,
We're very under-hyped!

> Televisions are normally bigger and contain more pixels. However these days many monitors are touch screens. In the same way touch screens "add" functionality, TVs subtract(yeah it's weak).

Anyone else feel free to steal my answer if you can come up with a better explanation for the iffy parts.

Comment: You should mention the initial letters of the lines in the 2nd verse! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [Quark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8821/4450) for figuring out the first 4 lines.

I'm a kaleidoscope of colors,
Red, blue, green of sorts
You use me everyday,
Even now you're using me,

> This refers to a computer screen.  Each pixel has red, blue, and green components.  I use a computer screen everyday, and I am using one to read this puzzle.

Or maybe my arch-rival...

> This is a printer.

Cool as he is, he's -
Mostly used offline!

> Not sure about this - most printers are not connected to the internet.

Yet, he's vital to many prints,

> Obviously a printer is vital to many prints.

My rival's smug, very, very smug,
He's comprised of more than me...

> Inkjet printers use CMYK (4 colors - cyan, magenta, yellow, key/black) instead of RGB (3 colors).

But he only subtracts, I add,

> CMYK is a subtractive color model, RGB is an additive color model.

Comment: Okay that's probably it, the arch rival part confused me but the rest fits perfectly.

Comment: You should mention the initial letters of the lines in the 2nd verse! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Nice job seeing that!